# Bazel build behind proxy

Tags: tensorflow, proxy, bazel

I would like to follow tensorflow example to build [generate_streaming_test_wav](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/audio_recognition) to generate test wav. And my bazel version is 0.16.1.

The problem is when I use command `bazel run tensorflow/examples/speech_commands:generate_streaming_test_wav`
, the following error message shown up:

```
xxx@xxx:~/kws/tensorflow-0911$ bazel run tensorflow/examples/speech_commands:generate_streaming_test_wav
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
ERROR: error loading package '': Encountered error while reading extension file 'closure/defs.bzl': no such package '@io_bazel_rules_closure//closure': Error downloading [https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/rules_closure/archive/dbb96841cc0a5fb2664c37822803b06dab20c7d1.tar.gz, https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_closure/archive/dbb96841cc0a5fb2664c37822803b06dab20c7d1.tar.gz] to /home/janet/.cache/bazel/_bazel_janet/2d14dc1ff5782da202e00efcc3cd86bc/external/io_bazel_rules_closure/dbb96841cc0a5fb2664c37822803b06dab20c7d1.tar.gz: All mirrors are down: []
ERROR: error loading package '': Encountered error while reading extension file 'closure/defs.bzl': no such package '@io_bazel_rules_closure//closure': Error downloading [https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/rules_closure/archive/dbb96841cc0a5fb2664c37822803b06dab20c7d1.tar.gz, https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_closure/archive/dbb96841cc0a5fb2664c37822803b06dab20c7d1.tar.gz] to /home/janet/.cache/bazel/_bazel_janet/2d14dc1ff5782da202e00efcc3cd86bc/external/io_bazel_rules_closure/dbb96841cc0a5fb2664c37822803b06dab20c7d1.tar.gz: All mirrors are down: []
INFO: Elapsed time: 57.573s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
```

However, I can use `wget` download those two packages. 
1.`https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/rules_closure/archive/dbb96841cc0a5fb2664c37822803b06dab20c7d1.tar.gz` 2.`https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_closure/archive/dbb96841cc0a5fb2664c37822803b06dab20c7d1.tar.gz`
I think my network should be fine. I have no idea why it can't download those files.

Any idea or suggestions would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a bug in Bazel's repository rules. If you'd be so kind to [file a bug](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/new), that'd be great!

As a workaround, extract the downloaded archive somewhere and replace the `io_bazel_rules_closure` rule in the `WORKSPACE` file with a `local_repository` rule pointing to the directory where you extracted the archive.

Comment: Thank you László. The workaround method works. However, the build process still stopped because tensorflow apply their rule (tf_http_archive) in the following step. Do you have any idea how to fix it? If you do, I would like to raise another question for that.

Answer (score 6):

If you know your proxy server, you should be able to set:

```
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://me:mypassword@myproxyserver.domain.com:myport
export HTTP_PROXY=http://me:mypassword@myproxyserver.domain.com:myport
```

and run the bazel build again.

If you don't know the proxy server used by wget check /etc/wgetrc or ~/.wgetrc

I've seen conflicting statements about HTTPS_PROXY and HTTP_PROXY being uppercase and lowercase, so you might try setting both. (Some have used unset to remove the lowercase settings. See: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/587#issuecomment-412531604)

Comment: Hi, William, I have tried the `export ...` commands, but it doesn't work, no matter uppercase or lowercase. I noticed that I am able to download those file through `wget`, but there are no proxy settings in my ~/.wgetrc file. Any other idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

create a folder say 'dist'.

Now whatever URL bazel is not able to download . 
do wget  inside that folder. ( wget normally works with most of proxy)

then run

```
'bazel build ...... --distdir  dist'
```

it will take packages from dist and compilation will do start.

Comment: I have done exactly this - BUT bazel still tries to download via http - so either this is not the complete answer OR there is another setting that is required?

Comment: U have to download packages one by one...untill all packages has been downloaded