# bazelisk proxyconnect tcp: net/http: TLS handshake timeout

Tags: linux, tensorflow, proxy, bazel

To build TensorFlow from source I installed `bazelisk` as recommended. Then when I call `./configure` which calls bazelisk I get the following error:

```
Downloading https://releases.bazel.build/0.29.1/release/bazel-0.29.1-lin
ux-x86_64...
2021/04/07 13:24:54 could not download Bazel: HTTP GET https://releases.bazel.build/0.29.1/r
elease/bazel-0.29.1-linux-x86_64 failed: Get "https://releases.bazel.build/0.29.1/release/ba
zel-0.29.1-linux-x86_64": proxyconnect tcp: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

Bazel is banned in the place I live and I set proxy to Tor to download it (via https://127.0.0.1:8118 through `privoxy`), but somehow it fails to download it. What's the solution?

Answer (score 1):

As said in the [docs](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk#about-bazelisk) bazelisk is just a wrapper that makes sure the version of bazel you are using to build is the best it can be.

Bazelisk does not yet have an [offline mode](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk/issues/88), and appears to always execute an http request or two on invocation.

This model doesn’t appear to work well with your internet settings, so it sounds like you might be better off manually downloading the appropriate release of bazel (check for a .bazelversion file in the project) using their [instructions for your platform](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/4.0.0/install-ubuntu.html#install-with-installer-ubuntu) for the direct binary installation, or if you can use the apt repositories, those appear to be more recommended.

With a direct installation of bazel, you may have to do a couple more things manually, but it won’t be doing those http requests to figure out the right version.

After that, you may find that other dependencies of tensorflow are blocked, and you may have to get bazel itself to use your proxy. Following the instructions for an [air gapped environment](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/guide.html#running-bazel-in-an-airgapped-environment) might be useful for building regularly, but you’ll still need to do the first build. [This SO answer appears to be a place to start for your proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52315366).

Comment: Thank you. I must say `sudo apt install bazel-0.29.1` didn't work in my case, which is my desired version. As for proxy, I set the `HTTPS_PROXY` to `https://127.0.0.1:8118` which is the port of privoxy that uses Tor, and it's working. The key is including `https` in this address otherwise some java classes can't distinguish the proxy.

Comment: I believe bazel is on 4.0 now. .29 strikes me as a very old version, not sure what bazel version that apt version maps to.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution, one can force `bazelisk` to download `bazel` from `github`. To do so you can set the following environment variable before running `./configure`

```
export BAZELISK_BASE_URL="https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download"
```